# How to show a property loaded from properties file in JSF page

Tags: jsf, properties-file

Is it possible, in a JSF page, to show a property loaded from a `project.properties` file (for example the database name)?

In **project.properties**:

```
cfg.bd.dbname=midatabase-name
```

In some jsf page some expression similar to this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cfg.bd.dbname}" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (ab)use [`<f:loadBundle>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/loadBundle.html) for this.

```
<f:loadBundle basename="project" var="project" />
...
<h:outputText value="#{project['cfg.bd.dbname']} />
```

I said *abuse*, because the `<f:loadBundle>` is initially intented to load localized text bundles which allows for internationalization, but as it's under the covers using the same type of properties files, you could as good use it for any arbitrary properties file in the classpath.

Comment: And, if the file is under WEB-INF? (Thanks)

Comment: No, just in the classpath. The above answer assumes it to be on the classpath root (i.e. not inside a package). If you have it inside a package, for example `com.exampe.config`, then you need `basename="com.example.config.project"` instead.